# Rails: Does associations slow down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, associations

All my models are connected using associations. I found myself, in all controllers, calling one entry model (Store model) to get everything I want: store products, products comments, store clients,... etc.

So, in the case I only want store info (location, phone,...), Rails gives me all store information I need, and all other associated information (clients, products,...). But I don't need them for that page and I don't use them.

**Does this (associations) alter negatively the performances of my app?**

If yes, what are best practices? Can I specify the association deep I need (until n-th child)?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge and experiences.

Comment: Ruby on Rails' ActiveRecord runs on the principle of 'lazy loading'— it'll only grab the data from the database when you require it.  It also caches data for you.

Comment: So, you mean that if I want to extract data, I call a .find method (for example) in the controller to display it on the view, it will be executed only when the corresponding code on the view is reached?

Comment: That's the way I'd do it, and it seems that's the way Rails does it too.  If you don't believe me, try `rails c` and run things like `ModelName.find(1)` (replacing ModelName with a model), and see when it executes the queries.